# Launch Windows Terminal from VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd, windows-terminal

I'm trying to launch the new Windows Terminal through VSCode like I have with other terminal emulators.

Previously I've used the following setting in the VSCode JSON file `settings.json` to launch Cmder through VSCode with ctrl+C

```
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Program Files\\cmder\\Cmder.exe",
```

However, trying the same with the directory of the Windows Terminal directory has been unsuccessful.

```
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.0.1401.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\\WindowsTerminal.exe",
```

Comment: You start these programs via a URL protocol. This line lists all of them (incl http etc). `@For /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%A in ('reg query HKCR /f "URL:*" /s /d ^| findstr /c:"URL:" ^| findstr /v /c:"URL: " ^| Sort') Do @Echo %%A %%B`. When you have the protocol name append `:// ` to it. So Weather app is `msnweather://`. You need to Shell Execute.

Comment: Alright, so I was able to navigate to the folder via Powershell and find the app ID in AppManifest.XML, so the following allows me to launch the terminal from VSCode

'shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App'

Unfortunately it isn't opening the folder I'm working in so that's something I need to work on.

Comment: I thought that the executable was `wt.exe`, so if I'm correct, you should be using `"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Users\\skillcap\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\wt.exe",` in your `settings.json`.  _(remember to change the user name as required)_. As the executable should also have added to your `%PATH%` you should be able to generally start it using just `wt`, _(with an unmodified `%PATHEXT%` variable)_. **Also added as answer**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought that the executable was `wt.exe`, so if I'm correct, in your `settings.json`, you should be using:

```json
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Users\\skillcap\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\wt.exe",
```

*(remember to change the user name as required)*.

As a side note, the executable should also have been added to your `%PATH%`, so you should be able to generally start it using just `wt`, (with an unmodified `%PATHEXT%` variable).